# Memberof attribute doesn't exist in my phpldapadmin schema

Tags: ldap, openldap, memberof

I'm pretty new to phpldapadmin and I'd like to use the memberof attribute to see which group an user is in, but I cannot find this attribute in the schema

http://i59.tinypic.com/2eex2xv.jpg

How can I add this attribute to my schema?

Answer (score 0):

The 'memberOf' attribute only exists in OpenLDAP, which I assume you're using, if you're using the 'memberof' overlay; and it will only appear for memberships which have been modified since you added the overlay.

It has nothing to do with phpldapadmin.

Comment: maybe i don't have the memberof overlay. how do i configure it?

Comment: Done, but having another problem. Memberof atribute doesn't belong to an objectclass, so how can i use it?

Comment: It doesn't have to belong to an object class. It's an operational attribute.

Comment: You can't set it. It is maintained automatically by the 'memberOf' overlay.